# Monitor incoming Kubernetes HTTP requests in Google Stackdriver

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a Google Kubernetes Engine running in the Google Cloud Platform.

I would now like to know how many HTTP requests are received by our Kubernetes cluster. I'd like that to be displayed in Google Stackdriver.

Unfortunately I can't find any appropriate metric in the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes.

Is there a way to get a chart with the count of all incoming HTTP request to a GKE cluster in Stackdriver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's a limitation of Kubernetes itself - it doesn't expose very much information about the services running in it.  You'll need to either install Istio and configure the Stackdriver adapter (see my [post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/istio-and-stackdriver-59d157282258) on this) or use something like [OpenCensus](https://opencensus.io) in your app to create a custom metric.  Another option would be to create a [log-based metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/) to count the requests.